# Computing the probabilities of 10 fair coin flips

Tags: probability

The specific problem I am trying to solve is

(a) The first and last toss are both heads.

I know that there are $2^{10}$ total configurations, but the probability of the first coin being heads is 1/2 and the probability of the last coin being heads is 1/2, so the probability of both being heads would be 1/4, or does the configuration of them limit the probability?

I think once I under this problem I can solve the rest of mine which are:

(b) Either the first toss or the last toss (or both) are heads.

(c) Either the first toss or the last toss (but not both) are heads.

(d) There are exactly k heads and 10 − k tails. Compute the probability for each

value of k between 0 and 10.

(e) There is an even number of heads.

(f) There is an odd number of heads.

Comment: Fixing some coins is the same that count only the others coins. Total possible sequences are $2^n$, if you fix some coin the possible different sequences with a coin fixed are $2^{n-1}$, and so on.

Comment: Your reasoning in part (a) is correct. To see why order doesn't matter: you are looking for the probability of the event that toss 1 is H, toss 2 is H or T, ..., toss 9 is H or T, and toss 10 is H. Since the probability of H on a given toss is $1/2$ and the probability of H or T on a given toss is $1$, and tosses are independent, this probability is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$. The order of the tosses is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

This is good situation in which to use the fractional definition of probability...$\frac{desired outcomes}{total outcomes}$

In this case the total is $2^{10}$.

How many ways can we write sequences where the first and last flip is heads? $2^8$ because the other 8 flips can be either heads or tails

$\frac{2^8}{2^{10}} = \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

> I know that there are $2^{10}$ total configurations, but the probability of the first coin being heads is 1/2 and the probability of the last coin being heads is 1/2, so the probability of both being heads would be 1/4, or does the configuration of them limit the probability?

Indeed not.   Consider this:   I toss a coin, I then toss the coin some *undisclosed* number of times (*maybe even none!*), then finally I toss the coin one more time.   What is the probability that the first and final coin toss both landed heads up?   **Yes, it is** $\bf 1/4$, because *why* would you need to know how many times I tossed the coin in the mean time?